# How to put command include ("/path/public_html/file.php"); inside a variable?

Tags: include

I have something like

`$example['description']="print this text: *** " ;`

and instead of *** I like to include a file /home/path/public_html/list.php where is stored the html text (php formatted).

How to implement the function

`include ("/home/path/public_html/list.php");`

inside the variable? Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be:

```
ob_start();
include "/home/path/public_html/list.php";
$text = ob_get_clean();
$example['description'] = "print this text: $text";
```